# Refresh layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to do some changes(change text, change positon ...) but it doesn't work.

For example in this function i'll change text of button correctly(i checked with getText function) but in view doesn't change anything.

When a button pressed, this function calls and change view. After this function, i want set view back.

```
setButton.setText("CHANGE RANGE");
setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

I also have another layout with imageView in this main layout. I also want change that image's position.

Comment: setContentView should be called before calling setButton

Comment: Can you please give more brief about how you want to change? whether going to show new layout or gonna show same layout with various values?

Comment: If you want to set a new layout, you have to use a different Activity.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys i have one main layout and it has got one layout for showing image. I want change buttons texts and image's position, size...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity
{

  Button setButton;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    setButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    setButton.setText("CHANGE RANGE");
  }
```

}

```
setButton.setText("CHANGE RANGE"); should be called after setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I called setText after setContentView but it doesn't change anything. I create new class. How can i call that class?

Comment: You can call a class by calling its constructor.Can you please post your updated code.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);setButton.setText("CHANGE RANGE"); RefreshActivity refreshActivity = new RefreshActivity();   Why just setText is not enough?

Comment: If possible,can you please post your whole class code? Not able to understand from this code snippet.

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I do other thing before this. After i call this, getText always give new text but view shows old one.